# Not able to navigate to pages on Windows Metro App using c#

Tags: c#, navigation, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

When my `UserLogin` page loads, i want to check for user database, and if it doesn't exist, or can't be read, i want to direct it to `NewUser` page.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    CheckForUser();
    if (UserExists == false)
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(NewUser));
}
```

The problem is that it never navigates to `NewUser`, even when i comment out the `if` condition.

Comment: have you check MSDN ** here is a link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211386.aspx **

Comment: I did not think you could navigate in the `OnNavigatedTo` method because you are still in the middle of a navigation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Navigate` can't be called directly form `OnNavigatedTo` method. You should invoke your code through `Dispatcher` and it will work:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    CheckForUser();
    if (UserExists == false)
        Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                            () => this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(NewUser)));
}
```

Comment: Be sure to call base.OnNavigatedTo(e) at the top of your overrided method call. I had this same code, minus the base.OnNavigatedTo(e) and I was still getting an exception. This answer helped me out, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your app tries to navigate before the current frame completely loaded. Dispatcher could be a nice solution, but you have to follow the syntax bellow.

using Windows.UI.Core;

```
    private async void to_navigate()
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage)));
    }
```

1. Replace MainPage with your desired page name.
2. Call this to_navigate() function.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this and see if this works

```
frame.Navigate(typeof(myPage)); // the name of your page replace with myPage
```

full example

```
    var cntnt = Window.Current.Content;
    var frame = cntnt as Frame;

    if (frame != null)
    { 
        frame.Navigate(typeof(myPage));
    }
    Window.Current.Activate();
```

or

if you want to use a 3rd party tool like Telerik try this link as well

[Classic Windows Forms, Stunning User Interface](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I see you override OnNavigatedTo method but do not call base method. It may be the source of problem.
Try calling base method before any logic:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    CheckForUser();
    if (UserExists == false)
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(NewUser));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Dispatcher.RunIdleAsync to postpone your navigation to another page until UserLogin page is completely loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The others are correct, but since Dispatcher doesn't work from the view model, here's how to do it there:

```
SynchronizationContext.Current.Post((o) =>
{
    // navigate here
}, null);
```