# Internet availability check - Navigate to Page - Windows Phone 8.1 - C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am a newbie! I want to check the internet availability when my app is launched as i am retrieving data from server. If internet is available, User can carry-on with app without any notification. If there in no internet, then I have to navigate to a specific page from my app.

I found some pages on stack overflow for this but there are old and for windows 8 or windows phone 8 not for WP8.1.

I am using the following namespaces...

System.Net.NetworkInformation, Windows.System, Windows.Networking.Connectivity and System.Net;

Tried using Bool, IPHostEntry, GetIsNetworkAvailable but everthing failed.

Can someone post a sample code? Will it be in app.xaml.cs and individual page's cs?

Below image is my try.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some help here [Check Internet Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676816/how-to-check-the-internet-connection-availability-in-windows-phone-8-application) and [Navigate to Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825085/not-able-to-navigate-to-pages-on-windows-metro-app-using-c-sharp) and managed to do what I wanted.

I write my code in MainPage.xaml.cs under "protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)". I am planning to execute this code on every page instead of registering for network change notification. Since this code uses await function, I added Async to the OnNavigatedTo event. Below is the code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, looking at the picture you provided, it seems you are trying to write code to class level. As far as I know, you can not really write if-else logic etc to class level, this should be a method-level code.

That said, to answer the actual question, I think it makes sense to look into [NetworkAvailabilityChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation.networkavailabilitychanged(v=vs.105).aspx).

[Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh487166(v=vs.105).aspx) at MSDN seems to be pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

as  you want to check the internet availability when **your app is launched**, you should move your code logic to inside method OnLaunched:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
   //paste your code here to check network
}
```

you can do it by click **plus** button on the left side method, to open bracket, and paste your code inside it.